# XML parsing using jQuery and append in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

```
<rows>
<row id='1'>    // parent
<cell>1</cell>
<cell>Task ABC0134</cell>

<row id="2"> // parent
<cell>1</cell>
<cell>Task ABC0134</cell>
</row>

<row id="3"> // parent
<cell>1</cell>
<cell>Task ABC0135</cell>
</row>

<row id="4"> // parent
<cell>1</cell>
<cell>Task ABC0136</cell>
</row>
</row>
```

I want to parse the above XML file and append that in the HTML table.

I found some code to parse that

```
$(this).find('cell').each(function(){});
```

but it gave me the whole cells it contains. I want to take the cells in the first row.but that row is the parent for all the cells.

so how to take that cells separately.

Comment: So you want cells in groups of two?  Like 1&2, and then 3&4, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution & code (Explanation in code comments)

```
//xml init
var xml = "<rows><row id='1'><cell>1</cell><cell>Task ABC0134</cell><row id='2'><cell>1</cell><cell>Task ABC0134</cell></row><row id='3'> <cell>1</cell><cell>Task ABC0135</cell></row><row id='4'><cell>1</cell><cell>Task ABC0136</cell></row></row>"

//get the first row's id - used for comparison later
var firstRowId = $(xml).find("row:first").attr("id");
//create "tr" string - for appending to table later
var tr = "<tr>";
//iterate over each <cell>
var cells = $(xml).find("cell").each(function (i) {
    //check if current cell's parent (<row>) 's id matches firstRowId
    if ($(this).parent("row").attr("id") === firstRowId) {
        //if yes go in, create <td>
        tr += "<td>" + $(this).text() + "</td>";
    }
});
//finish the string
tr += "</tr>";
//apend to table
$("table").append(tr);
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/Uf95P/

Comment: I need the values of cells which is in first row only.Not their child row cells.

Comment: so basically you need to access the first row? the row with `id=1`?

Comment: I need cells from first row but not from their child rows like (id 2,3,4).

Comment: @Saravanan check my answer, is that what u want

Comment: we dont know how many cells are there.its dynamically created.

Comment: No cell is dynamically created. not 2 it is may be 3 or 10 it will come based on dynamic.

Comment: but will the id=1 for `row` be same?

Comment: No Id also created dynamically.

Comment: will it altleast be the first row all the time?